# Is it safe to use //1 as Math.floor in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I thought

```
Math.random() * (max-min) // 1
```

would be shorter and comfortable than

```
Math.floor Math.random() * (max-min)
```

But I'm not sure whether the former is safe or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usage is explicitly supported by the specs. So it is quite safe to use `//` as you intend. To quote [the doc](http://coffeescript.org/):

> To simplify math expressions [...] `//` performs integer division

And latter:

```
CoffeeScript        JavaScript
-------------------------------------

a // b              Math.floor(a / b)
```

Please note this operator was added in CoffeScript 1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know about the `//` operator but if we take a look at the JavaScript output of both versions we see that they are equivalent.

First:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) / 1);`

Second:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));`

(Dividing a number by 1 in JavaScript has no effect)